# hide status bar on xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I feel kinda dumb asking this but I really am confused right now. I need to hide the status bar when video goes fullscreen but I keep getting

> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Activity.Window'

I tried making an instance of Activity class but that throws NullReferenceException.

Activity.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); //to hide

So how do I use this method to hide status bar only when the video is in fullscreen?

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    WebView web_view;
    
   

    public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }

  
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SupportActionBar.Hide();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        
        var relativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.container);
        var relativeLayoutTwo = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.containerTwo);
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.SetWebChromeClient(new FullScreenClient(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutTwo));
        



        BottomNavigationView navigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation);
        navigation.SetOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public class FullScreenClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        readonly FrameLayout.LayoutParams matchParentLayout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                                                                                                         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        readonly ViewGroup content;
        readonly ViewGroup parent;
        View customView;
       
        public FullScreenClient(ViewGroup parent, ViewGroup content)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.content = content;
        }

        public override void OnShowCustomView(View view, ICustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            customView = view;
            view.LayoutParameters = matchParentLayout;
            parent.AddView(view);
            content.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            **Activity.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);**
        }

        public override void OnHideCustomView()
        {
            content.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            parent.RemoveView(customView);
            customView = null;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've been using C# for 20 years but even I don't have the error codes memorized.  Please post the error message AND the code, and tell us which specific line causes it.

Comment: sorry, my bad. Added the error message to the post and put the code line in **-**.

Comment: you don't need a reference to "an instance" of Activity, you need a reference to the currently running instance.  There are lots of existing posts about how to get a reference to the current activity, and even a plugin to help - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I've installed the plugin but I've also found out that Xamarin.Essentials has a similar thing. At this point I can't figure out how I make a reference to the current activity. To be honest, I'm having hard time guessing what a current activity is and how to store it so I could apply "Activity.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);" to it. I tried googling but I couldn't find any related examples. Sorry but bear with me a little.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/

Comment: So basically, current activities are methods which are executed at a certain moment. There are default activities like onStart, onPause and etc, but also like in my case, i have custom activities like OnShowCustomView. I need this activity to be referenced as an object? It makes little sense since I am going to execute the same method. The difference is that this custom method is in a subclass of MainActivity which doesn't inherit Activity class and that keeps me from getting what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I've used Xamarin.Essentials namespace and in each custom method I made a MainActivity class instance and set it equal to (MainActivity)Platform.CurrentActivity; and through that instance I was able to use Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

```
 MainActivity hideBar = new MainActivity();
            hideBar = (MainActivity)Platform.CurrentActivity;
            hideBar.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```